# CSS Layout - div covering screen size

Tags: html, css, layout, background

I am a novice at CSS/HTML and need help with a certain issue.  I am trying to make my opening div (w/ background image) cover the entire screen (which I have done successfully).  The problem is, no matter what I try, I cannot get the next div to start after the initial div.  I am including my HTML and CSS.  Problem is that I cannot cause #map-contain to start after #opening.  Thought it would simply be 'positioning' issue but I cannot solve this.  Please help.  http://jsfiddle.net/nELQF/ - (need black div to start at bottom of red div)

HTML

```
<div id="opening">
</div>
<div id="map-section">
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#opening {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-image: url('DSC_0577.JPG');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#map-section {
width: 100%;
height: 800px;
background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the top element is absolutely positioned, you could do the same with the second element and set `top:100%` in order prevent the elements from overlapping.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9QLUt/)

```
#map-section {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 800px;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

As an alternative, an arguably better approach allowing you to avoid having to absolutely position both elements would be to simply set a height of `100%` on the `html`/`body` elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz8rb/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton.  Knew it was something simple, I've just been off today.  Really appreciate it!